# Why does gatsby-plugin-google-gtag includes analytics.js and gtag.js?

Tags: plugins, gatsby, gtag.js, analytics.js

The plugin gatsby-plugin-google-gtag adds analytics.js and gtag.js to my website. This reduces my page speed insights score. Isn't gtag.js enough ? Why do we need analytics.js ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the Gatsby plugin that's adding `analytics.js`; it's Google.

I was confused by this as well when we were migrating from `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics` to `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`, as my expectation was to see `analytics.js` disappear and be replaced by `gtag.js` in the built website.  Instead, like you, I saw *both* `analytics.js` and `gtag.js` getting loaded and thought something was wrong.

It turns out that Google's current implementation of `gtag.js` is largely a wrapper around their older ("legacy", according to Google) product integration scripts like `analytics.js` for Google Analytics and `conversion_async.js` for Google Ads.  Depending on which identifiers you feed to `gtag.js`, it will load these other scripts, whichever ones are applicable.

You can test this yourself by using your favorite ad/content blocker to stop `gtag.js` from loading on your website.  Notice that, if you do this, the HTML to load `analytics.js` is nowhere to be found in the page's source code.  That's because it is only injected into the code later by `gtag.js` at runtime, rather than by anything at Gatsby build time.  If `gtag.js` never runs, the tag for `analytics.js` is never injected into the page.

Your page speed insights score has likely decreased because `gtag.js` is a sizeable chunk of JavaScript, and then it goes and loads the same old big `analytics.js` you were using before.  One might ask, if I only use Google Analytics and none of the other products for which `gtag.js` can grab metrics, then why should I load the large `gtag.js` library just to chainload `analytics.js` instead of just loading `analytics.js` directly?  I think there's a good argument to be made in favor of doing this, but I still favor going with `gtag.js` myself.  Google themselves are heavily pushing adoption of `gtag.js` over direct calls to `analytics.js`, and I don't think there's any guarantee that just because `gtag.js` is wrapping `analytics.js` today it will still be doing so tomorrow.  Basic laws of API usage apply: as a developer, I should be writing to the interface and not counting on particularities of the implementation, since those can be changed by the API provider at will as long as the interface remains stable.